# How to calculate the position and direction of the target cursor in xna?

Tags: c#, xna, cursor, position, game-engine

I developped a small games like "minecraft". and I'm stuck for a few days on the calculation of the direction of the cursor.
Let me explain.
I would like to target a cube with my cursor in the middle of the screen and make it disappear with a click. But I do not see any how to recover this information ..
Can someone point me to a "sample / tutorial" or explanation please?
Thank you very much.

My screenShoot picture game :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take no credit for most of this--it's what I used in my 3D XNA game and it worked.  The comments are fairly explanative.  Basically it projects a `Ray` straight from your cursor position and checks to see if it `Intersects()` the boundingsphere of any map objects (`Unit`s in this case)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a Ray translating screen cursor position into screen position
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="projectionMatrix"></param>
    /// <param name="viewMatrix"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Ray CalculateCursorRay(Matrix projectionMatrix, Matrix viewMatrix)
    {
        // create 2 positions in screenspace using the cursor position. 0 is as
        // close as possible to the camera, 1 is as far away as possible.
        Vector3 nearSource = new Vector3(mousePosition, 0f);
        Vector3 farSource = new Vector3(mousePosition, 1f);

        // use Viewport.Unproject to tell what those two screen space positions
        // would be in world space. we'll need the projection matrix and view
        // matrix, which we have saved as member variables. We also need a world
        // matrix, which can just be identity.
        Vector3 nearPoint = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Unproject(nearSource,
            projectionMatrix, viewMatrix, Matrix.Identity);

        Vector3 farPoint = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Unproject(farSource,
            projectionMatrix, viewMatrix, Matrix.Identity);

        // find the direction vector that goes from the nearPoint to the farPoint
        // and normalize it....
        Vector3 direction = farPoint - nearPoint;
        direction.Normalize();

        // and then create a new ray using nearPoint as the source.
        return new Ray(nearPoint, direction);
    }

    private Vector3 cursorRayToCoords(Ray ray, Vector3 cameraPos)
    {
        Nullable<float> distance = ray.Intersects(new Plane(Vector3.Up, 0.0f));
        if (distance == null)
            return Vector3.Zero;
        else
        {
            return cameraPos + ray.Direction * (float)distance;
        }
    }

    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        cursorRay = CalculateCursorRay(camera.Projection, camera.View);
        cursorOnMapPos = cursorRayToCoords(cursorRay, cursorRay.Position);
        checkInput(gameTime);

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the nearest unit to the cursor
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The unit nearest to the cursor</returns>
    private Unit getCursorUnit()
    {
        Unit closestUnit = null;
        float? nearestDistance = null;
        float? checkIntersect = null;

        foreach (Unit unit in map.Units)//checks to see if unit selection
        {
            checkIntersect = cursorRay.Intersects(unit.BoundingSphere);
            if (checkIntersect != null)//if intersection detected
            {
                if (nearestDistance == null) //first unit found
                {
                    closestUnit = unit;
                    nearestDistance = (float)checkIntersect;
                }
                else if ((float)checkIntersect < (float)nearestDistance)//for any others, only find the nearest
                {
                    closestUnit = unit;
                    nearestDistance = (float)checkIntersect;
                }
            }
        }

        return closestUnit;
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much! I see that your answer is similar to the tutorial by linker "DoWhileFor." Sorry but I'm always up your answer;-)

Comment: Oh, you can probably ignore `cursorRayToCoords()`.  It's a function to find where the cursor intersects the x/y plane

Comment: Mhh. This feature seems useful to me! This is exactly what I need .. So I can know about it is the box model handpicked?!

Comment: Good afternoon.
Can you tell me when and where you initialize the array [map]? Thanks ;-)

Comment: You mean `map.Units`?  That you could add to either at the start, in the `map` initialization, and it would be added to / taken away from in response to actions (like building units, firing bullets, etc.).  You can check out Crater's source (the game) at http://self.openmix.co/portfolio/

Answer (score 2):

Of course it widely depends on how you have your data organized.
But if you have your polygon and meshes somewhere stored(and i'm not talking about vertex buffers!!), like in an octree, you can do something like this:

You create a ray from your camera settings and "fire" it through your scene. Usually a octree, or similar structures, can be extended to easily make a ray test to return the hit elements. Of course you could bruteforce iterate all your quads, but this will be very soon a performance bottleneck.
From there you can use the result for what ever you want.

This whole process is usually called "picking" and [this](http://ghoshehsoft.wordpress.com/2010/11/25/xna-picking-tutorial-part-i/) is a really nice tutorial about it.

Comment: Hey! Thank you very much for that answer. It includes everything I needed! A very good tutorial and explanation.