# 3D graphics: Changing object's world position relative to it's screen position

Tags: 3d, orthogonal

I am implementing a game with a camera view like in Diablo 3 (3d objects on a 3d surface, top-down view), but I have one limitation:

I need my game to disregard distance in any respect.

That includes having all the 3d models face the camera from the same angle in ANY place on the screen, having the same size in any place on the screen and moving with the same speed (screenspace-wise).

I need this due to the specific mechanics I have in mind and I need it to be in a 3d world, because I what to have accurate shadows in the game.

I know how to implement every feature (mainly by using orthogonal projection and some shader magic) but the last one, that is I can't understand how to move a 3d object, positioned on a 3d plane with the very same speed screenspace-wise.

If the object is in the upper part of the screen, it will move slower, and vise versa, so I do need some code to compensate for that.

Do you guys have any idea how this can be done?

P.S. Thanks for editing btw, it does look better.

Edit: I am coding in c#/XNA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not very neat math, but I hope it works for you:

### Input

Suppose you are given a

- worldViewPerspectiveMatrix `M` (Transforms world space to perspective space, orthogonal matrices should work as well!)
- a constant velocity (more specifcally a distance per Frame) in screen space `v_screen`
- a (normalized) direction vector `V_dir` in world space, this will give the direction your object moves. The actual length of the vector will be calculated.
- a position `X` where your Object is placed in world space.

### Result

- a scaling factor `a` for moving your object 'v_screen' units in screen space along `V_dir` in world space. Thus you want to move your object actually `X += a*V_dir`.

First we use the formula of mapping the *world space* to *screen space* by using homogenous coordinates and w-clipping. The `.` denotes the matrix multiplication operator.

```
X_proj := M.(x,y,z,1);
X_screen := (x_proj/w_proj,y_proj/w_proj);
```

From there we can specify the position of the object `X` in screen space and the position after appling the directional movement `X+(a*V_dir)`.

The length in screenspace and therefore the desired distance (per frame) is simply

```
Length[(X+(a*dir))_screen - X_screen] == v_screen.
```

Let's solve this for `a`. I used my Mathematica to calculate `a` for you. If you want further details, I may elabourate the answer.
Suppose `M`, `X`, and `V_dir` is

```
         / xp \          / vx \                        / vxp \
X_proj = | yp |  V_dir = | vy |    V_proj = M.V_dir =  | vyp |
         | zp |          | vz |                        | vzp |
         \ wp /          \ 0  /                        \ vwp /
```

And `v_screen` is your desired screen space velocity.
Then `a` is:

```
vlen = v_screen*v_screen;
a = (-dwp*vlen*wp + dxp*xp + dyp*yp + 
    0.5*Sqrt(
       Power(-2*dwp*vlen*wp + 2*dxp*xp + 2*dyp*yp,2)  - 
       4*(dxp*dxp + dyp*dyp - dwp*dwp*vlen)*(xp*xp + yp*yp - wp*wp*vlen)
       )
    ) /
    (dxp*dxp + dyp*dyp - dwp*dwp*vlen);
```

Remember, `-a` is also a solution.

Comment: I did not mention that I am coding in c#/XNA, maybe there is a build-in function there that already computes this? Because for me trying to code your explanation is really scary :).

Comment: Erm yes I think it is :) ... I just found the problem interessting: finding a constant screen space velocity. I try to modify my answer to XNA/C# code if you like. Another Solution I actually would propose is to define all movements in *screen space*. Then you map the screen space position to your 3d Plane by [ray casting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.xna.framework.ray.aspx)

Comment: My game has some specific mechanics that I need be implemented as well as some visual effects. Namely I need characters to move with screen-space speed to allow for smooth aiming (the aiming will happen through movement) but also I need the characters to explode in a number of gory bits when they die :). And as the second part would most likely be implemented manually (physics engine integration would be an overkill and too difficult), I would prefer for the characters to be actually positioned on a plane in a 3d world, so I can have more flexibility creating realistically-looking gore :).

Comment: In any case I would HUGELY appreciate a c# code or at least some useful functions and I would definitely delve into ray casting link you provided.

Comment: Disregard my post #3, I got your point now :). Most likely ray casting is the way to go if there are no ready c#/xna implementation.

Comment: Sorry for linking a german page ... here is the english one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.ray.intersects.aspx . There you can calculate the distance to a plane. The only thing remaining is calculating the ray from a screen space position. But this is a solved question :( ... [click me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626248/how-to-calculate-the-position-and-direction-of-the-target-cursor-in-xna)

Answer (score -1):

Guess what, due to the specifics of the orthogonal view, simply specifying the orthogonal matrix as Projection solved all problems by itself. The models move with the same speed and keep the size nomatter where they are positioned. However, the only problem is the fact that when you change screen resolution the world does not adapt to it. So we have to use scale factors that rely on the current screen resolution to scale our world manually when the game is loaded.